# Passing in a List<Interface> parameter

Tags: java, interface

I'm using a method:

```
public List<IRecord> combineTypes(List<IRecord>)
```

Which will take the required values from the IRecord objects and combine like values, updating and returning the updated list.

However, `IRecord` is an interface. I'm attempting to call the `combineTypes()` method on passing in a list of an object that implements the IRecord interface:

For example, the `CoverageRecord` class implements `IRecord`

and I am trying to call

```
combineTypes(data)
```

where `data` is a `List<CoverageRecord>`

But my compiler is throwing an error, saying I am passing in an invalid argument.

Is there a workaround or something I am missing? I feel like I'm just brain-farting.

Comment: Is `List<CoverageRec>` a typo for `List<CoverageRecord>`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: @AntonH yes it is, I'll fix it for clarity. Also forgot to mention that the combineTypes returns a List<IRecord>

Comment: @ZouZou thank you, reading that over led me to a fix! I knew I was forgetting something relatively simple.

Comment: Wow, it seems that [I recently got some superpowers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-superpowers) and now can close questions with tag I have gold badge all by myself, without waiting for approval of other users with moderation privileges. If you think your question is not duplicate feel free to inform me about it and I will reopen it for you.

Comment: @Pshemo You're a superhero ;-)

Comment: @Pshemo No, it very well could be, I just didn't know how to phrase it better (long day) and didn't see a similar question after looking for a little bit. Zouzou led me to the documentation I needed, so keep it closed

Comment: @zomgcopters Sorry, actually you should start by reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html :) That will solve the issue you are facing. So to answer your question `combineTypes(List<? extends IRecord> list)` should do the trick.

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks! Everything is working great now!